Change network interface back to old naming convention - eth0
I am running docker-desktop and using docker compose for containers.  I cannot create a ipvlan using the interface name enp2s0 docker compose expects eth0.  How can I revert and persist the old naming convention for network interfaces in Ubuntu 23.10

does this help?

Does this answer your question? Use of Predictable Network Interface Names with alternate kernels

You can use Netplan to rename your network interface to eth0. Here’s how you can do it:
Edit the Netplan configuration file: Open the Netplan configuration file located in /etc/netplan/. The file is typically named something like 01-netcfg.yaml or 50-cloud-init.yaml. Use a text editor such as nano to edit the file. For example:
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

Modify the configuration: Update the configuration to include the match and set-name keys. This will tell Netplan to match the current interface and rename it to eth0. Here’s an example configuration:
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  # Your interface's MAC address
      set-name: eth0
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.100/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4

Make sure to replace xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx with the actual MAC address of your network interface and set your ip address properly.
You can find the MAC address using the following command.
sudo ip link

Apply the changes and reboot. This should have changed the name of your network interface.
